# Logitech Brio OpenCV Capture Settings

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to record from a Logitech Brio at 60fps, preferably at 1080p.
It should work because I can get it working on OBS and many others have achieved the settings.

Here is the code I am using to try to capture at this rate:

```
    // Do some grabbing
    cv::VideoCapture video_capture;
    video_capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
    video_capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
    video_capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 60);
    {
        INFO_STREAM("Attempting to capture from device: " << device);
        video_capture = cv::VideoCapture(device);

        // Read a first frame often empty in camera
        cv::Mat captured_image;
        video_capture >> captured_image;
    }

    if (!video_capture.isOpened())
    {
        FATAL_STREAM("Failed to open video source");
        return 1;
    }
    else INFO_STREAM("Device or file opened");

    cv::Mat captured_image;
    video_capture >> captured_image;
```

What should I be doing differently for the Brio?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem: same camera, couldn't change resolution or fps . After hours of working on this and digging the internet I found a solution: 
Need to use DSHOW and need to instead read from capture device 1 (instead of 0). Code below for reference

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open(cameraNumber + 1 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)
```

sorry I only did this in Python, but I hope the same solution works in c++
I assume you can do something along the lines of

```
video_capture = cv::VideoCapture(device + 1 + cv::CAP_DSHOW);
```

Comment: This solved my issue. It seemed like it was always outputting 480p no matter what I changed the frame size to.  Doing DSHOW instead of just flat cv2.VideoCapture(0) made it crystal clear. Only change I had to make is mine is cap.open(cameraNumber + cv2.CAP_DSHOW) and my cameraNumber is 0.

Answer (score 4):

With OpenCV 4.1.0, this achieved 4K video under Windows, with my Logitech BRIO.  The important thing in the end seemed to be to use CAP_DSHOW and to set the resolution after initialising the camera, not before.

```
cv::VideoCapture capture;
capture = cv::VideoCapture(cv::CAP_DSHOW);
if (!capture.isOpened())
{
    cerr << "ERROR: Can't initialize camera capture" << endl;
    return 1;
}

capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 3840);
capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 2160);
capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem has nothing to do with the camera. The code might not work because you are creating a separate scope for opening the video capture. Upon exiting that scope, the destructor of video_capture instance will be called and therefore the !isOpened() check will always return true. I can't understand why you use those braces. Instead it should be:

```
    INFO_STREAM("Attempting to capture from device: " << device);
    auto video_capture = cv::VideoCapture(device);
    if (!video_capture.isOpened())
    {
        FATAL_STREAM("Failed to open video source");
        return 1;
    }

    cv::Mat captured_image;
    video_capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
    video_capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
    video_capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 60);

    INFO_STREAM("Device or file opened");
    video_capture >> captured_image;
```

Comment: Unfortunately my captured_image is still 480x640 for some reason and 30fps.  Is there something else that might be wrong other than the OpenCV code?

Comment: I am unable to replicate the problem because I don't have the hardware. The code itself seems to be fine. There might be a problem handshaking the target resolution with the webcam driver. 480x640 is VGA, kind of like failsafe mode. It might have to do with some specific settings like the apiPreference/codec. Take a look here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a85b55cf6a4a50451367ba96b65218ba1 . Only a certain combination of settings might work for full hd retrieval, or it might not work at all. Have you tried reading stream from that webcam with gstreamer?

Comment: I don't understand how this code is supposed to work - you're creating a `VideoCapture` that's not connected to a camera, setting the resolution and FPS then overwriting this with a connection to the actual camera.

Comment: You are right! It's a very old answer and there is indeed a bug in my code. I corrected it now.

Comment: Just a sidenote: in the Opencv forums I read that sometimes a little delay was necessary between opening the capture device and setting the parameters. So putting in some time.sleep(1) or the c++ equivalent might make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting of my own, I found that @ffarhour's solution worked for me.

> ```
> fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
> cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
> cap.open(cameraNumber + 1 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
> cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc)
> cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
> cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
> cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)
> ```

But for anyone troubleshooting this in the future, I also want to add that you need a good USB cable and preferably direct access to a usb 3.0 port. I had the camera in my dock first, and only 1080p worked.

A good check is the windows 10 built in camera tool. My experience is that high resolutions will only show as options here, if your cable and usb port support it. So do not bother with Opencv if this does not work first.

Aditionally for those just starting out: the code snippit above goes **before** your opencv while loop. and Inside your while loop you add:

```
while True:
 ret, frame = cap.read()
 frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, 1)
 cv2.imshow('original image', frame)
 cv2.waitKey(2)
```

Finally I want to note that 30 fps worked best for me (better than 24 fps) and that the max available resolution from the camera is NOT 3840 x 2160 pixel but **4096 x 2160**, how cool is that?

I also strongly advise to download the logitech driver for brio called 'logitech camera settings' it allows you to set the FOV, autofocus and other things you otherwise could never access.

Answer (score 0):

There are already many good answers, but I encountered some additional issues that I want to address in addition.

First, let's discuss some possible reasons if you are not able to get the desired FPS or resolution:

1. Make sure your webcam is plugged into the right USB port (A **USB 3.0 webcam** plugged in **USB 2.0 port** (or extension cords) will work, but might not provide all resolutions or framerates)
2. Use the right codec. For example **fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')** some resolutions/fps requires the camera to pass the data in a compressed way.
3. Choose the appropriate backend. On Windows using **cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)** or **cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_MSMF)** might be working for you. Keep on mind that **cv2.CAP_MSMF** or **cv2.CAP_DSHOW** provide different resolution/fps etc. for the same camera.

Additionally, you can check the formats supported by your webcam using ffmpeg (if installed). List all your devices with the following command:

> ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

To list all formats for a specific device (e.g., "BRIO 4K Stream Edition"), use the following command:

> ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="BRIO 4K Stream Edition"

If you are sure your device supports the desired format with the chosen backend, you can use the following code to set the resolution and other properties:

```
cam_index = 1  # index of your camera
# vid = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_index, cv2.CAP_MSMF)
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_index, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
width = 1920
height = 1080
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)

if not vid.isOpened():
    print(f"Failed to open camera {cam_index}")
    return
```

I hope this information helps you